# Solve inequality with primes

Tags: number-theory

> Solve inequality
>   $$n-m+1 < p_m$$
>   for $m=[n/2]$, where $p_m$ is $m$-th prime number.

Comment: What does the square bracket notation mean?

Comment: @ColmBhandal I assume that it's the greatest integer function.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have any ideas on this problem (it looks like a homework problem).

Comment: Please check the statement, when $n=2$, $m=1$ so $n-m+1=2$ which is not less than the first prime number, $2$.

Comment: **Hint:**  For each integer $k\geq 5$, $p_k\geq 2k+1$.  This can be done by induction on $k$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 2):

$$n-m+1 \le p_m$$

For $m=[n/2]$, where $p_m$ is $m$-th prime number and the brackets represent the greatest integer function. As mentioned by Michael your original inequality has a counter example so I changed it to an less than or equal sign.

$$n-m+1=n-[n/2]+1 \le n-n/2+1 = n/2+1 \le p_{[n/2]}$$

So we only have to prove,

$$n/2+1 \le p_{[n/2]}$$

Observe that $n=2$ and $n=3$ satisfy the inequality. Also note that after $p_2$ the gap between primes is always greater than one.

Proof: Note that even numbers after 2 cannot be prime since 2 would divide them.

Since, $n=2$ and $n=3$ work, and $n/2+1$ only grows by a half for each increase in $n$, the above inequality is true and thus,

$$n-m+1 \le p_m$$